# Agora.io websdk example gives error ERR_DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KE

Tags: agora.io

I am following sample example from
https://github.com/technophilic/Agora-demo-web

When I run it with "live-server" it gives following error:

```
Agora-SDK [ERROR]: User join failed [ERR_DYNAMIC_USE_STATIC_KE]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648919/we-are-implementing-the-agora-screen-sharing-and-getting-error-dynamic-use-stati/60659947#60659947

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link for the solution to your issue.

https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/token_error#120-dynamic-user-using-the-static-key

Contact us for any further assistance.