# Error in Agora VideoChat SDK 3.1.1 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I was using Agora SDK(v3.1.1) to implement a Web video chat application using Java Script but it keeps on showing error "Error: DYNAMIC_STATIC_KEY"
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide some more details, along with a code snippet, so the question is easily understandable. Otherwise, people will just skip it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648919/we-are-implementing-the-agora-screen-sharing-and-getting-error-dynamic-use-stati/60659947#60659947